# Objective C constructor

Tags: objective-c, constructor

I have a C++ background and I'm going through a Obj C tutorial.. I got a question about the following line:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
```

So exactly what's happening here? I assume that

1. my color pointer doesn't point to the redColor object right? (Otherwise the code should be

   ```
   UIColor *color = redColor;
   ```
2. Instead I'm creating a new color object, and is being initialized with the `redColor` variable

If 2 is true, then I'm trying to look at `UIColor.h` and see how the constructor works (ie, I'm looking for some copy constructor type code).

But I don't see any

```
(UIColor *) init : (UIColor *) color;
```

and that constructor should have some implementation like the following:

```
self.r = r;
self.b = b;
self.g = g;
```

which function does this or is it all generated by default?

Comment: Objective-C has no constructors.

Comment: `[UIColor redColor]` is a [*class method*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassMethod.html). It's a method that is called directly on the class without an instance.

Comment: You  will see that `redColor`  method is start with `+` that indicate that it is a class method and it can't be called with an instance of a class.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, Objective-C has no constructors, it has initializers. There are some important differences, to name a few: initializers are inherited, initializers can be called multiple times (but you shouldn't do it). In essence, they behave the same as any other method.

All initializers in Obj-C start with `init...`. `UIColor` has multiple initializers, for example `-initWithWhite:alpha:`.

`+[UIColor redColor]` is a factory method. It is a class method (a method on a class). We could implement it in the following manner:

```
+ (UIColor *)redColor { // we would actually use instancetype instead of UIColor

    return [[self alloc] initWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Of course, the real implementation probably returns a singleton.

You might notice that most initializers have a factory method with the same parameters, e.g.: `-initWithWhite:alpha:` pairs with `+colorWithWhite:alpha:`. Factory methods were very useful in pre-ARC memory management where the usual way to create an object was:

```
UIColor *color = [[[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:0 alpha:0] autorelease];
```

and using a factory method

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0];
```

was much shorter and easier to type.

Regarding your question about copy constructor, in Objective-C the behavior is usually implemented using the `NSCopying` protocol. You would get an object copy just by calling `[myColor copy]`. However, note that `UIColor` is an immutable class (you cannot change its properties without creating new instance) therefore there is never a reason to create a copy of a color.

Comment: Nice explanation. I'll leave my answer here, but I think yours is better.

Answer (score 1):

When making a class, you can make "class methods" and "instance methods".

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

+ (void)aClassMethod;
- (void)anInstanceMethod;

@end
```

Class methods are called like

```
[MyClass aClassMethod];
```

Instance methods are called like

```
[object anInstanceMethod];
```

So in your case, `redColor` is a Class method.